# Docker : React App doesn't read environment variable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a React App running using Docker. I want to deploy the same docker image on dev, staging and prod environment.

The value of my React environment variable (REACT_APP_PARAM) is different for each environment.

My dockerfile  look like this :

```
…

COPY . .

ARG REACT_APP_PARAM

ENV REACT_APP_PARAM $ REACT_APP_PARAM

…
```

I use this Dockecompose file to build my image

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    image: my-image
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - REACT_APP_PARAM=BuildParam
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_PARAM=${REACT_APP_PARAM}
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
```

When deploy and run my image on dev environment I use this dockercompose file

```
version: "3"

services:
  frontend:
    image: my-image
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_PARAM=DevelopmentParam
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
```

When I debug my application the value of REACT_APP_PARAM is still BuildParam

But went I list my container environment variable with command docker exec my-image env, the value of REACT_APP_PARAM is  DevelopmentParam.

Any ideas how I can solve this or how is the best approach to archive that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After several searches, I found that Environment variables are embedded into the build.

The official React documentation :

> The environment variables are embedded during the build time. Since
> Create React App produces a static HTML/CSS/JS bundle, it can’t
> possibly read them at runtime. To read them at runtime, you would need
> to load HTML into memory on the server and replace placeholders in
> runtime, as described here. Alternatively you can rebuild the app on
> the server anytime you change them.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

I don't like the idea to build different image for each environment.